# Default Current Year selected

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table called Sales and Calender.

When the year is selected from the slicer it should show the selected year values, if not should show the default current year. For example, if I select 2021, it should show us 2021. If I am not select any year from the slicer it should show me 2023 since 2023 is the current year.

Comment: I tried this DAX query but it's not working 

Selected Year = 
IF (
    ISFILTERED (Calender[date].[Year]),
    YEAR(DATE(MAX(Calender[date].[Year]),1,1)),
    YEAR(TODAY())
)